# yyyy-mm-dd format with strtotime returning wrong result

Tags: php, strtotime

```
$originalDate1 = '2013-12-30';

echo $newDate = date("o-m-d", strtotime($originalDate1));
```

Displaying **2014** instead of 2013

Comment: Your date is already in Y-m-d format, why to reconvert again in that format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the "o"

ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

You should use "Y" instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for logical answer

Answer (score 1):

use `Y-m-d` instead of `o-m-d`

```
$originalDate1 = '2013-12-30';

echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate1)); // will output 2014-12-30
```